# flaskform insert data for values in stringfield

Tags: flask, insert, flask-wtforms

When I create a class for a form with Flaskform or wtforms, I can specify default values for Stringfields.

```python
class MyForm(FlaskForm):
info = StringField("MyId", validators=[DataRequired()], default="Defaultinfo")
```

But my question is, if I want to make this default value variable, how do I do that?

Here is an idea that does not work. I just don't know how to pass a variable with data to the form object

```python
class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    def __init__(self, myid):
       self.myid = myid
       info = StringField("MyId", validators=[DataRequired()], default=self.myid)

@app.route("/index", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    infos = ("1", "Berlin",
            "https://hostname.com", "bla", "blub", "prod")
    myid = infos[0]
    form = MyForm(myid) # not Possible
```

Unfortunately, I have not yet found out how to pass this data to the form object, so I can insert a value from this tuple into the string field

Greetings niesel

Answer (score 0):

```
form.info.default = myid
```

it was so easy